# jQuery UI dialog won't let me do AutoPostback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

When I click on a RadioButton I need to do a postback so that It can run my RadioButton code.(AutoPostback="true"). I have my Radio button in a jQuery UI dialog and when I click on the button nothing happens and I get an error :

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 404

I read somewehre that the dialog actually places itself outside the form?
I added this to my Javascript function to prevent it:

```
function getFiles(canDo) {
        //create Popup with content from div
        $('#file').dialog({//file is the div where my controls are
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    debugger;

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');

                }
            }
        });
        $('#file').appendTo($("form:first"));
    }
```

Any ideas on why It won't successfully do a postback? or why I get that error?

My CONTROLS:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
                 <div id="casefiles">
            <%--<div id="rbfileByHolder" runat="server">--%>
                <label>
                    Sort By</label>
                <span>
                    <asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" ID="rbMyFiles" Text="My Files"
                        Checked="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rbMyFiles_CheckedChanged" /></span>
                <span>
                    <asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" ID="rbByFileID" Text="By File ID"
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rbByFileID_CheckedChanged" /></span>
                <span>
                    <asp:RadioButton class="aspRBs" GroupName="rbfileByNameOrID" ID="rbByFileName" Text="By File Name"
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rbByFileName_CheckedChanged" /></span>
           <%-- </div>--%>
            <br />
            <label>
                Select New CaseFile</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" DataTextField="Display"
                DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="524px" 
                 />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCaseFiles"
                ToolTip="Casefile Required" InitialValue="-1" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="ddlExtCaseFiles" runat="server" PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
                TargetControlID="ddlCaseFiles" BehaviorID="ddlExtCaseFiles" Enabled="True" />
          </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbByFileName" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbByFileID" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbMyFiles" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCaseFiles" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OSCIDConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="p_CaseFiles_ListActiveCaseFiles" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="InvestigatorID" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCaseFilesReverse" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OSCIDConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="p_CaseFiles_ListActiveCaseFilesReverse" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="InvestigatorID" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyCaseFiles" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OSCIDConnectionString %>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="p_CaseFiles_ListActiveCaseFilesAssignedTo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="InvestigatorID" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="AssignedTo" SessionField="InvestigatorID" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Comment: where have you placed your ScriptManager? or ToolkitScriptManager

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">     ...........CONTROLS.............   they are all inside the <form> tag

Comment: can you paste your file div or some more code to give us detailed knowledge of code flow...

Comment: <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934%28v=vs.100%29.aspx> try to get some more info on the error..

Comment: added my body in the main question

Comment: try to put any other cntrl that will postback the update panel ...like checkbox & use the same event ...test it just to see if you get the same error??? If you get the same error then its because of the JQuery and update panel event binding issue..

Comment: It's been a little while since I did this, but I believe that I had to put my entire form inside the DIV representing my dialog in order to get things to work.

Comment: @user1084319 Just try a hack ....use 2 update panels...for dropdown a radio btn.. hope it works-out :)

Comment: I've tried 2 updatePanels before. Still gave me the same error

Comment: Remove the Update Panel. Jquery does not work well with Update Panel.